# Numpy Array Change indices

Tags: python, numpy

I have an numpy-array with 32 x 32 x 3 pictures with `X_train.shape: (32, 32, 3, 73257)`. However, I would like to have the following array-shape: (73257, 32, 32, 3).

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to archive this either `np.reshape(x, ndims)` or `np.transpose(x, dims)`.

For pictures I propose `np.transpose(x, dims)` which can be applied using 
`X_train = np.transpose(X_train, (3,0,1,2))`.

Comment: Thank you, this is correct. np.reshape did destroy the images, np.transpose worked as suggested :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do a [transpose](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.transpose.html)

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> a
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
>>> a.transpose()
array([[1, 3],
       [2, 4]])
>>> a.transpose((1, 0))
array([[1, 3],
       [2, 4]])
>>> a.transpose(1, 0)
array([[1, 3],
       [2, 4]])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
np.reshape(X_train, (73257, 32, 32, 3))
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

Comment: Better check that on a small sample.  Transpose is right if you want to preserve images.